# How can I set a Neo field's values from my plugin/module?

Tags: saveentry, plugin-neo

I wish to programmatically set the value of a Neo field.
This is my current approach:

```
$entryData = self::setupEntryData($item);
$entry = new Entry($entryData);

$fieldValues = [
    'heading' => $entryData['title'],
    'blocks' => [
        'blocks' => [
            'new0' => [
                'modified' => 1,
                'type' => 'wysiwyg',
                'enabled' => 1,
                'collapsed' => 0,
                'level' => 0,
                'fields' => [
                    'grayBackground' => true,
                    'wysiwyg' => '<p>test</p>',
                    'buttons' => null,
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ],
];

$entry->setFieldValues($fieldValues);
```

Of course this doesn't work.
Can someone point me in the right direction?
Here is a screenshot of the Form Data that is passed when setting the value manually from Craft CMS.
[image]

Just to confirm, my Neo field is called `blocks`.
My target blog type has a handle of `wysiwyg`.
The Redactor field I target has a handle of `wysiwyg`.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I just figured it out.

For anyone facing the same issue, here is what worked for me:

```
$entryData = self::setupEntryData($item);
$entry = new Entry($entryData);

$fieldValues = [
    'blocks' => [ // Neo field handle
        'new0' => [
            'modified' => 1,
            'type' => 'wysiwyg', // Neo block handle
            'enabled' => 1,
            'collapsed' => 0,
            'level' => 0,
            'fields' => [
                'grayBackground' => true, // Neo block field
                'wysiwyg' => '<p>test</p>', // Neo block field
                'buttons' => null, // Neo block field
            ]
        ]
    ],
];

$entry->setFieldValues($fieldValues);
```