# Programatically create a Neo block with children

Tags: plugin-development, craft3, plugin-neo

I already discovered how to create a neo block programmatically from this post: [How can I set a Neo field's values from my plugin/module?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/35451/how-can-i-set-a-neo-fields-values-from-my-plugin-module)

However, I don't know how I can create a neo block with child blocks.

So the idea is I want something like this:

```
[
    'blocks' => [ // Neo field handle
        'new0' => [
            'modified' => 1,
            'type' => 'topLevel', // Top level neo block
            'enabled' => 1,
            'collapsed' => 0,
            'level' => 0,
            'fields' => [
                'someField' => true, // Neo block field
            ],
            'children' => [
                'new0' => [
                    'modified' => 1,
                    'type' => 'secondLevel', // child neo block
                    'enabled' => 1,
                    'collapsed' => 0,
                    'level' => 0,
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

The `children` array is just what I imagine the solution might be like. But this doesn't work.

Does anybody know how it should be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out. You have to create a separate block and it somehow figures out it's a child based on the level you specify. So something like this:

```
[
    'new1' = [
        'modified' => 1,
        'type' => 'parentBlock',
        'enabled' => 1,
        'collapsed' => 0,
        'level' => 0,
        'fields' => [
            'theme' => 'black',
        ],
    ],
    'new2'= [
        'modified' => 1,
        'type' => 'childBlock',
        'enabled' => 1,
        'collapsed' => 0,
        'level' => 1, // increment the level
        'fields' => [
            'value' => 'text',
        ],
    ]
]
```